# How to enable ipv6 support in linux system

Tags: networking, internet, ip, ipv6

I am trying to enable ipv6 support to my linux system. Im trying to modify `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` this file but system is not allowing to do so.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 12.04 does same thing will also work on other linux system like fedora..

Comment: Care to tell us how you modify it? I sure hope you use "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6" as -root-. and do not forget to check `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: In my system ipv6 is enabled.

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 0`

Comment: yes, it should be enabled by default? Maybe it is disabled in the network-manager? (check nm-connection-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Command is wrong nfs mount command should be

`mount -t nfs [2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912]:/home/abhitesh /home/mount/`

`IPv6` address should be in `[]`

And for CIFS mount command should be

`mount -t cifs -o username=root,password=fedora //2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:914/public /home/mount`